# Remove empty rows from dataframe in the python function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to find specific rows in a huge dataframe and assign a comment if the condition is met.

The part of the code I use is as follows:

```
def check_car(x):
        if x['CAR'] == 'FERRARI' and x['COUNTRY'] != 'ITALY':
            return 'This is wrong'
        else:
            x.drop()
```

After that I use this function to create new data frame with ID and comment.
The new data frame contain IDs with `“This is wrong”` as well as `None` values.
Instead of that I want to remove all None values from data frame, is it possible to do that in the function itself?

I used `x.drop` but I got the error:

```
ValueError: ("Need to specify at least one of 'labels', 'index' or 'columns'”)
```

Comment: Are you able to show us your sample input and output ?

Answer (score 0):

First pick all the columns satisfying  your condition, then assign them values.
Try:

```
df = df.loc[ (df['CAR'] == 'FERRARI') & (df['COUNTRY'] != 'ITALY')]
df.loc["COLUMN" ] = "This is wrong"
```

Comment: I tried that one but how to attach to column with comments the next column with IDs from original data frame for which the condition is satisfied?